# Dynamic file path for IDE setting?

Tags: ide, filepath, application-settings, usb-flash-drive

Can you set the drive letter to be dynamically added for an Windows application setting on a flash-USB?

Would it be an environment variable, and if so what would it be called? -> (i.e. *%root%/Qt/4.8.1/bin*)

**Issue Example:**

I have Qt SDK 1.2.1 installed on my flash drive for plug and play on any workstation without the environment.  The issue is if the drive letter isn't assigned to be the same as when I installed it, things wont link or compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach (if your IDE supports this) could be to use an environment variable to refer to the drive name.  Then when you know the letter, set the env. var to the appropriate value.

*Note*: depending on your OS you might need to restart your IDE to pick up the change in the env. variable

Comment: Do you have any idea to what a USB may use for a drive path when calling itself?  I wish I could simply call, %ROOT%.  I actual just thought of that and will try it.

Comment: @BrandonClark - if you are asking about the env. var. name, I don't know of any conventions -- but you can name it almost anything (e.g. USB_DRIVE, or your suggestion, ROOT)

Comment: I had a suggestion like that a min ago.  The problem with that is if I am restricted from editing environment variables than the program wont run.  Its a way for me to use it on a school computer or at work(yes, i can get away with doing this.  Not abusing my employment.).

Comment: Unless your IDE has a way to read variables in some other way (e.g. a configuration/properties file), I think you are out of luck.  OTOH, I think you should be able to edit your own environment variables, so I'm pretty sure you can use the approach outlined above